# Can I get an idToken from an auth0 rule?

Tags: auth0

Is there a way that I can get access to the idtoken that would have been generated on a user creation in the auth0 rules context?

I'd like to sync user registrations to my backend system and need the idtoken that the auth0 signup would have generated.  That way I can http post that data in my rules trigger.

Comment: I think I might be misunderstanding what your asking. In my Auth0 app when I log someone in I set the id.Token to local storage as well as the profile information. Then I retrieve it from localstorage. Is that what your talking about? I have a SPA I can show you an example in if so.

Comment: I'm trying to set up a backend server side trigger to a graph.cool service - without a client.  Unfortunately, the graph.cool service requires a userId token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because the ID token is only generated when all rules finish executing. The reason for this is that further rules might deny the user from authenticating or modify their profile before the actual token gets generated.

The proper way to do this would be to define your backend as a resource server on Auth0, and use Client Credentials from the rule: https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/grant/client-credentials.

Another alternative is to call the [Auth0 Management API](https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2) to fetch user information from your backend when necessary.

Comment: If I call a webtask from the rule, and this webtask calls an auth0 authenticate api to get a token - would it work, or could there be some sort of race condition because the user record would not have been generated yet?